# How do I get the CPU time used effectively by my program (java)?

Tags: java

I'm working in a code in java which I must send to an external computer to run. So far in my computer I was using this function to get  an idea of time (real time was enough until now)

```
     long start;
     long end;
    start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    //
    %code
    //
    end   = System.currentTimeMillis();
    time=(float) ((end - start)/1000.);
```

But then I realized, the computer distribute the CPU time expended among the users, so the execution is "paused" several seconds until is the turn of my run again, therefore I get a time which is not accurate. I investigated and implemented this example based on the answer of  [Recording Program's CPU Time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14788976/recording-programs-cpu-time) :

```
    try {

       ThreadMXBean thread = ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean();

       long cpu = thread.getCurrentThreadCpuTime();
       long user= thread.getCurrentThreadUserTime() ;
       Thread.sleep(300);
       int i=0;
       while(i<100000){
           System.out.println("hola");
           i++;
       }
       cpu =( thread.getCurrentThreadCpuTime() - cpu ) ;
       user=( thread.getCurrentThreadUserTime() -user );
       System.out.println("Cpu:"+cpu);
       System.out.println("User:"+user);
   }
   catch (InterruptedException _) {}
```

for example I've gotten these results:

Cpu:1218750000 > User:593750000

Cpu:1453125000 >User:750000000

is thread.getCurrentThreadUserTime() the function I need for my case?

Answer (score 0):

I have never used this ThreadMXBean although it would have been useful sometimes in the past :)

Anyway, the JavaDoc tells

> **long getCurrentThreadUserTime()**
>
> Returns the CPU time that the current thread has executed in user mode in nanoseconds. The returned value is of nanoseconds precision but not necessarily nanoseconds accuracy.
>   This is a convenient method for local management use and is equivalent to calling:
>
> getThreadUserTime(Thread.currentThread().getId());
>
> Returns:
>   the user-level CPU time for the current thread if CPU time measurement is enabled; -1 otherwise.
>   Throws:
>   UnsupportedOperationException - if the Java virtual machine does not support CPU time measurement for the current thread.
>   See Also:
>   getCurrentThreadCpuTime(), isCurrentThreadCpuTimeSupported(), isThreadCpuTimeEnabled(), setThreadCpuTimeEnabled(boolean)

So what you are doing seems to be correct. You may ask yourself why the numbers are so high, they are returned in **nanoseconds**.